# (Python Cmd) sqlite3 commit not occuring without restarting the application

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, python-cmd

I am having an issue with sqlite3 and the python cmd library.
I am making a simple shell app to generate a random sample of warmup exercises from a database using sqlite3.
Here is the full code as it is fairly short :

```
import cmd
import sqlite3
from random import randint, sample

# Connect database & create cursor
db = sqlite3.connect('warmupsdb')
cursor = db.cursor()

# Get every exercise in the database
warmupsdb = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM warmups").fetchall()

# Get the length of the database for error checking
warmupslen = len(warmupsdb)



class warmups(cmd.Cmd):
    intro = "Hello World !"
    prompt = "warmups > "
    """Simple cmd program."""

    def do_gen (self, number):
        if is_validInt(number):
            number = int(number)
            gen = sample(warmupsdb, number)
            for output in gen:
                print(output[1])
        else:
            print("Please provide a valid number.")

    def do_add(self, text):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO warmups (warmupName) VALUES (?)", (text,))
        db.commit()

    def do_exit(self,line):
        db.close()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    warmups().cmdloop()
```

My issue arises in the `do_add()`function, no error arises but the committed changes do not appear in the application until I restart it.
For example if my database has the sample :

```
"Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"
```

And I use the command

```
add Test 4
```

The `gen` command will never give back "Test 4" as it seems it is not yet in the database which is not the behavior I intended, I would like to be able to generate samples that have been added during the current instance.

I have tried to find information in the documentation of sqlite3 and cmd, and also on this specific issue but there isn't a lot of information on the usage of the cmd library in conjunction with an sql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items are added to the database, but you use old data fetched at the beginning of script with SELECT statement.

```
warmupsdb = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM warmups").fetchall()
```

You need to update the data you operate on.
E.g. function do_add can be extended with the following refresh of data:

```
global warmupsdb
warmupsdb = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM warmups").fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at global scope:

```py
# Get every exercise in the database
warmupsdb = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM warmups").fetchall()
```

When this is executed `warmupsdb` will be set to a list of all the rows that are *currently* in the database at startup time. No matter how many rows you may be adding to the database during execution, you have not modified `warmupsdb`. Yet your method `gen` is returning a sample taken from this initial list of rows. So it's only when you restart the code and `warmupsdb` is set again that the rows added in the previous run will be reflected.

I would suggest code such as the following:

```py
import cmd
import sqlite3
from random import randint, sample

class warmups(cmd.Cmd):
    """Simple cmd program."""
    intro = "Hello World !"
    prompt = "warmups > "

    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self._db = sqlite3.connect('warmupsdb')

    def do_gen (self, number):
        try:
            number = int(number)
            if number < 1:
                raise ValueError('Non-positive number')
        except ValueError:
            print("Please provide a valid positive number.")
        else:
            # Get every exercise in the database
            cursor = self._db.cursor()
            warmupsdb = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM warmups").fetchall()
            gen = sample(warmupsdb, number)
            for output in gen:
                print(output[1])

    def do_add(self, text):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO warmups (warmupName) VALUES (?)", (text,))
        self._db.commit()

    def do_exit(self,line):
        self._db.close()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    warmups().cmdloop()
```

Note how the sqlite connection, being crucial to the operation of class `warmups`, is now encapsulated in that class.

I would also suggest you take a look at the [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).